# php code to download file not working with ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am using ajax to called download.php page , but it is not working .What could the problem in below code .

AJAX::

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'downloadsample.php',
  data: {
  imagepath: "../ReportCard/imagepost.png"
  },
   success:function(data)   { 
    alert('sample download done ');
    }

    });
```

PHP Code ::

```
<?php

if ( isset($_POST["imagepath"]) && !empty($_POST["imagepath"]) ) { 
$file = $_POST['imagepath'];

    // Fetch the file info.
    if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
    }
    else {
        die('The provided file path is not valid.');
    }

}
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't download file directly by ajax. you can redirect the user to your download page or you can try with iframe. i mean use hidden iframe or generate iframe dynamically what ever you like and put source of this iframe to your download URL.

Comment: i ajax return i should create i frame and then what?

Comment: you can return download url from ajax and on ajax success create iframe and put that url to iframe source

Answer (score 0):

you can't do it through Ajax because JavaScript cannot save files directly to a user's computer (out of security concerns). Unfortunately pointing the main window's URL at your file download means you have little control over what the user experience is when a file download occurs.

Try [jQuery File Download](http://johnculviner.com/post/2012/03/22/Ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads-with-jQuery-File-Download.aspx) which allows for an "Ajax like" experience with file downloads complete with OnSuccess and OnFailure callbacks to provide for a better user experience. Take a look at [blog post](http://johnculviner.com/post/2012/03/22/Ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads-with-jQuery-File-Download.aspx) on the common problem that the plugin solves and some ways to use it and also a [demo of jQuery File Download](http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/) in action. Here is the [source](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload/blob/master/src/Scripts/jquery.fileDownload.js)

Here is a simple use case demo using the plugin [source](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload/blob/master/src/Scripts/jquery.fileDownload.js) with promises. The demo page includes many other, 'better UX' examples as well.

```
 $.fileDownload('some/file.pdf')
    .done(function () { alert('File download a success!'); })
    .fail(function () { alert('File download failed!'); });
```